# Can't see some stored procedures in sys.procedures

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, stored-procedures, documentation

Documenting a database and find that I cannot see stored procedures in `sys.procedures`, even though I can see them in Object Explorer.

```
select p.name, x.value, p.modify_date
from sys.procedures p
left join sys.extended_properties x
on p.object_id = x.major_id
where p.is_ms_shipped = 0
and p.name NOT LIKE 'sp_%'
```

Comment: Maybe leave out the filter `and p.name not like 'sp_%'`?

Comment: Have you thought about not building html in SQL? Query the metadata tables as you are and use a proper language for string building/html emission?

Comment: I agree with @billinkc I think you may be overcomplicating this problem.

Comment: I agree.  This is what I happen when I start something at wee hours in the morning without coffee. I will shift my approach entirely by abandoning building html in SQL.  I also tried leaving out the p.name not like 'sp_%' and it still didn't return anything.

Comment: I wish I could Upvote Shawn for that edit. You sir are a saint.

Comment: Are you sure you have any procedures? What does `SELECT name FROM sys.procedures;` return? (You don't really need those filters anyway - `sys.procedures` is already filtered to non-system procedures, even though if you are in master a couple might squeak though.)

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand Good point. I am an idiot and tired.

Comment: @WayneFitz don't beat yourself up too hard there guy.

Comment: When I try that query SELECT name FROM sys.procedures, it returns no results, but when I look in the Programmability folder under non-system stored procs there are hundreds of objects there.  I think someone may have put them in an odd place.  I have to use SELECT obj.Name SPName, sc.TEXT SPText
FROM sys.syscomments sc
INNER JOIN sys.objects obj ON sc.Id = obj.OBJECT_ID
WHERE TYPE IN ('P','V');
 to find anything

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense - are they under a schema you don't have access to? Are you sure you're in the right database? Are you sure your query that "works" isn't just getting views (e.g. try limiting it to just `'P'`)?

Comment: No, it is getting the stored procedures, too. Aaron, you are exactly right!  I only started a few days ago, and I guess they never gave me access to the schema where they are stored.  I wish I could upvote your comment.

Comment: Not sure why you posted 100+ lines of unformatted code for us to read, when it's only one four line query that's relevant.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I've fixed that.

Comment: Thanks, I apologized for the excess.  I guess I was seeking out if my approach was right, which it wasn't since you shouldn't use sql to output html.  Trimmed down the question and answer are much clearer.

Comment: @WayneFitz: 1. Get rest, or you will do some damage. 2. Run `select name from sysobjects where type = 'p' and name NOT LIKE 'sp_%' order by name`. If that does not return the same procedures as in OE, than you are not connecting to the same server in OE and query window.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To ensure you can see the objects you are looking for:

- Make sure you are in the right database / right instance - seems simple and silly but it happens all the time. This also includes not using things like `AttachDbFileName` in your connection string - this means that two different programs will actually have two separate copies of your database, so if one adds a procedure, the other will never see it.
- Don't add unnecessary filters that don't accomplish anything (`sys.procedures` already filters out system objects, and if you use the `sp_` prefix for your own procedures - [which you shouldn't](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix) - you probably don't want that filter to leave those objects out, either).
- Validate that you have `VIEW DEFINITION` access to all of the potential schemas where these objects may live. These are going to be protected in the metadata / catalog views but may still be exposed to you in certain scenarios under Object Explorer (especially if your Object Explorer connection is running under a different context than your query window(s)).

Also note that these are potential answers for future readers too, not just for the current OP (who we now know had an issue with the last bullet).

Comment: Database does not matter. This query will return correct result w/ or w/o filter from any DB. His only concern should be connecting to the `same server` in OE and query window. And there is always `select name from sysobjects where type = 'p' and name NOT LIKE 'sp_%' order by name` that he can use to validate his original query.

Comment: @ajeh huh? So if he is looking under AdventureWorks in Object Explorer and running a query against master, that shouldn't matter?

Comment: No. DB name of the query window is obvious from the toolbar, while the server name is not visible in SSMS. If he is missing procs, than he must not be in the same server between OE and query window.

Comment: Running `select @@servername as server, db_name() as db` before the main query would be a definitive answer to this hypothesis :)

Comment: @ajeh if you know to check that, or are awake enough to be thinking clearly. Remember too that the answer to a question here is not meant just for this asker but also future askers and searchers as well. So just because you are so sure that this OP could never make a mistake like running in the wrong database, plenty of other people could.

Comment: @ajeh also, I don't know what version of Management Studio you're using, but you can certainly see server name at least in the status bar [here's mine](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rHurP.png), and you can also configure query windows to show it in the tab (I forget if it's shown by default; first thing I change). So saying that it's very likely they're on the wrong server, but impossible they're in the wrong database because it's so "obvious," is really kind of silly.

Comment: The answer for me was permissions. The DBA had to add rights to the system schema on master for my user profile.  Once this was done, everything worked as intended.  I was using the correct database and the filter wasn't the only issue.  I guess the solution ended up being a DBA fix, and it took over 30 minutes to figure it out.  I already had master access to dbo, system state access, and access to system objects, which confused our dba why I couldn't query sys.procedures.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my specific instance of this issue was permissions.  The DBA had to add datareader rights to the system schema on master for my user profile. Once this was done, everything worked as intended.  He tried adding dbo owner rights, and granting view definition to just sys.procedures and that did not work.

The bizarre symptom is that I could still query select * from sys.all_objects, but none of the non-system stored procedures were present in the results.

Comment: Isn't this covered by my bullet "Validate that you have `VIEW DEFINITION` access..."?

Comment: Yes. I added this specific solution because my DBA knew it was an permissions issue, but tried giving me access to master and even a specific grant to the sys.procedures table. The trick is you have to ensure explicit access for datareader rights for the system schema.  It took him over 30 minutes to figure that out.

Comment: So "Validate that you have `VIEW DEFINITION` access to all of the potential schemas" wasn't clear enough but had I said "Validate that you have 'datareader rights' to all of the potential schemas" it would have been? Can you share the actual `GRANT` statement he issued to give you 'datareader rights' on a schema? Did you mean `GRANT VIEW DEFINITION`, and not `datareader rights` or `GRANT SELECT`?

Comment: The takeaway is you can't grant someone access to master and expect it to cover all schemas and you can't specifically grant view access to a specific sys table if the user profile doesn't have access to the sys schema.  My DBA is convinced that's a bug or maybe he's just new or dumb.

Comment: Well, granting view definition to sys.procedures means you can say `EXEC sp_helptext N'sys.procedures';` to view the definition of that stored procedure, not that you can select from it. And granting select to it would *still* hide from the results any object for which you don't have `VIEW DEFINITION`. And granting object- or schema-level permissions to a user in master does not affect the login's users in any other databases. So yeah, maybe your DBA needs to brush up a bit.